# How to set up the parameters in dllimport function in VB.NET similar to "as Any" in VB6

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net, vb6

I met a problem as the following while updating my GUI from VB6 to VB.NET.

I have a test.DLL file (implemented by C++) containing the function

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) short WINAPI Trans(USHORT Id, HEADERTYPE *SendHeader, char *SendData, HEADERTYPE *RecvHeader, char
*RecvData) //HEADERTYPE is a defined structure
```

In VB6, the function Trans can work correctly by setting

```
Declare Function Trans Lib "test.dll" ( _
ByVal Id As Integer, SendHeader As HEADERTYPE, SendData As Any, _
RecvHeader As HEADERTYPE, RecvData As Any) As Integer
```

I know the declaration "As Any" can not be used in VB.NET and the function Trans can work by replacing the type "Any" by the type of SendData and SendData.

However, in the GUI implemented by VB6, the function Trans is widely used with a large amount of different type declaration of SendData and RecvData.

Therefore, please provide me the answer to find out the declaration and setting of a useful object in VB.NET that is similar to the object "Any".

I tried the following setting by using "Object" instead of "Any", but it can not work.

```
DllImport("test.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)

Public Function Trans( _
    ByVal iServerId As Short, ByRef SendHeader As HEADERTYPE, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)> ByRef SendData As Object, _
    ByRef RecvHeader As HEADERTYPE, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)> ByRef RecvData As Object) As Short
End Function
```

Sincerely thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match the pinvoke signature to the signature of the C++ function being invoked.

In your C++ DLL Trans' SendData argument is a char*, which generally matches to a VB.Net String or StringBuilder (for in or in/out respectively).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried to replace "Object" by "String" and tested UnmanagedType.LPStr(LPWStr,LPTStr,BStr,TBStr,VBByRefStr or AnsiBStr), but it still failed.